# Grant access to a specific future table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, database-permissions, fivetran

I'm currently using Fivetran to pipe data into Snowflake. Once the data has landed, every 6 hours DBT runs some simple saved queries, which appear as tables in a schema.
However, the permissions for various roles keep being reset and they can no longer access the tables in that schema that I gave them permission to see. I suspect this is because DBT is dropping and then re-creating the tables in question.

One possible solution is to grant access to future tables in the schema, e.g.:

```
grant select on future tables in schema myschema to role some_role;
```

However, I just want to give access to a single table, not all. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally possible with [post-hooks](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/hooks-operations#hooks)! Used in concert with `{{ this }}` ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/this)), they're a powerful and flexible tool.

You have two options for providing access on a single table using post-hooks:

- as a config block at the top of the model definition file (below), or
- in the `dbt_project.yml`

```
{{ config(
    post_hook=[
      "grant select on {{ this }} to role some_role;"
    ]
) }}

select ...
```

Here's a more [in-depth guide](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/the-exact-grant-statements-we-use-in-a-dbt-project/430) to granting access in a dbt project

p.s. love your username!

Comment: Thanks so much! This works very well.